# AngularJS: two way data binding not working in nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to `AngularJS`. I am using nested `ng-repeat` to generate multiple forms. And form data is json which is dynamic. So the problem is Data binding for `TEXT`, `TEXTAREA` and `SELECT` input is not working.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/gTc5v/10/

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="form in forms">
         <h2>{{form.name}}</h2>

         <div ng-repeat="field in form.form_fields">

         <div ng-If="showElement(field,'RADIO')">
         <div>   
         <h3>{{field.caption}}</h3>
         <span ng-repeat="option in field.optionValues">
         <input ng-model="field.answer" type="radio" value="{{option}}" >{{option}}
            <br/></input>
         </span>
         </div>
         </div>

         <div ng-If="showElement(field,'TEXT')">
         <input ng-model="field.answer" type="text" placeholder="{{field.caption}}" />
         </div>

         <div ng-If="showElement(field,'PARAGRAPH_TEXT')">
         <textarea ng-model="field.answer" placeholder="{{field.caption}}"></textarea>
         </div>

         <div ng-If="showElement(field,'LIST')">
         <div>
         <h3>{{field.caption}}</h3>
         <select ng-model="field.answer">
            <option ng-repeat="option in field.optionValues">{{option}}</option>
         </select>
         </div>
         </div>

         <div ng-If="showElement(field,'CHECKBOX')">
         <div>
         <h3>{{field.caption}}</h3>
         <span ng-repeat="option in field.optionValues">
             <input ng-checked="field.answers.indexOf(option) != -1" ng-click="toggleCheck(field.answers,option)" type="checkbox">{{option}}
             <br/></input>
         </span>
         </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <br/>
     <div ng-repeat="field in form.form_fields">
     {{field.caption}} : {{field.answer}}{{field.answers}}
     </div>
     <br/>

 </div>
```

**AangularJS:**

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('ngIf', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        if (scope.$eval(attrs.ngIf)) {
            // remove '<div ng-if...></div>'
            element.replaceWith(element.children());
        } else {
            element.replaceWith(' ');
        }
    }
};
});

function ctrl($scope) {

    $scope.fields = [{
        "caption": "Gender",
        "questionType": "RADIO",
        "optionValues": ["Male", "Female"],
        "fieldPriority": "INCLUDE"
     }, {
        "caption": "City",
        "questionType": "TEXT",
        "optionValues": "",
        "fieldPriority": "INCLUDE"
     }, {
        "caption": "Address",
        "questionType": "PARAGRAPH_TEXT",
        "optionValues": "",
        "fieldPriority": "INCLUDE"
     }, {
        "caption": "Nationality",
        "questionType": "LIST",
        "optionValues": ["Indian", "American"],
        "fieldPriority": "INCLUDE"
     }, {
        "caption": "Tea/Coffee",
        "questionType": "CHECKBOX",
        "optionValues": ["Tea", "Coffee"],
        "fieldPriority": "INCLUDE"
     }];

    angular.forEach($scope.fields, function(field) {
        if(field.questionType == 'CHECKBOX'){
           field.answers = [];
        } else{
           field.answer = "";
        }
    });

    $scope.forms = [{"name":"Form 1","form_fields" : angular.copy($scope.fields)},{"name":"Form 2","form_fields" : angular.copy($scope.fields)}];

    $scope.showElement = function (field, type) {
        return field.questionType == type;
    };

    $scope.toggleCheck = function (answer, option) {
        if (answer.indexOf(option) === -1) {
            answer.push(option);
        } else {
            answer.splice(answer.indexOf(option), 1);
        }
    };
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove element.replaceWith below in your directive link function.

```
element.replaceWith(element.children());
```

You don't need to call replaceWith() in directive because directive has wrapped the template content and it will be included once compiled.

Here is a workable [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gTc5v/11/)

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need your own `ng-If` directive? Your example works fine if you use the built-in [ng-if](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf).

Note that in either case you need to write it as a lower-case `ng-if` in your HTML.

**Update**:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gTc5v/12/)

Comment: thanks for reply. can you post `JSFiddle`. because i tried what you said, but not working.

Comment: Sure: http://jsfiddle.net/gTc5v/12/

It seems that the example requires angularjs 1.2+. I also changed the way the select element is defined: you shouldn't use `ng-repeat` there, but `ng-options` instead (`ng-options="option for option in field.optionValues"`)

Comment: Yes, @srdan is right. And you can also add a prompt option like this: <option value="">please select</option> for fixing empty option issue.